# Kafka resets offset to earliest accidentally

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

My kafka server resets consumer groups offsets to the earliest accidentally when kafka crashes (due to hardware issue - out of storage or 1 node disconnect). This is the second time I have this problem and there is no easy way I could restart the offset to the last hour before the incident happened (I can set offset for each partition manually in zookeeper but there are 100 partitions for each topic and we have 20 topics).

I have no clue where the issue could be (zookeeper? kafka? consumer? producer?). It just happens when kafka is backed up from the crash. I do not aware any error or warning.

I use kafka 0.8.2.2 and exhibitor (zookeeper) v1.5.5

Comment: What do you set for config `auto.offset.reset`? You could try to set it to `largest`. Besides, the new kafka version supports seeking offsets by timestamp.

Comment: it is `smallest`. However, it should happen for new consumer groups. why does `auto.offset.reset` matter in this case? yes, I have read somewhere about kafka offset by timstamp but upgrade to new version requires many changes to our source code, so it will not happen in a few days for me.

Comment: There is no new consumer for Kafka 0.8.2.2. Since `auto.offset.reset` is set to smallest, Kafka sets the offset to the earliest/smallest one when it finds the last-recorded offset was already out of range.